# How can I get a new image not cached in android coil?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am developing an android app using the Jetpack Compose with Coil ImageLoader library.

It shows a user's profile image.

I receive the profile data from the API. `GET: /users/{userId}`

The response contains `userId` and `profileImgKey`.

For the user profile image, Backend provides `GET: /photo/{userId}` API.

But the problem is that if some user update his/her profile image, other users still see the previous profile image not the new image.

Because it is cached by Coil.

If I turn-off the caching option, it may work fine.
But I don't want to do it.
I don't want to lose the performance benefit.

When the user update their profile image, the `profileImgKey` is changed.
So I want to use this as a cache key.

But I don't know how to use this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Coil **2.0.0** working with network cache is significantly simplified.

Specify `diskCacheKey` and `memoryCacheKey` in `rememberAsyncImagePainter`, also [`key`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#key(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Function0)) is still needed to trigger recomposition.

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current
key(key) {
    Image(
        rememberAsyncImagePainter(
            remember(url) {
                ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                    .data(url)
                    .diskCacheKey(url)
                    .memoryCacheKey(url)
                    .build()
            }
        ),
        null
    )
}
```

And clear cache using image loader:

```kotlin
val imageLoader = context.imageLoader
imageLoader.diskCache?.remove(url)
imageLoader.memoryCache?.remove(MemoryCache.Key(url))
```

---

Answer for Coil **1.4.0**

Coil has a cache on two levels:

1. For network calls Coil uses OkHttp, to access its cache you need to create it manually as shown in [documentation](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/image_loaders/#caching). I think in this case it's best to store both the cache and the image loader in the DI, but you can also create a composition local to access this cache from any composable:

   ```kotlin
   val LocalCoilHttpCache = staticCompositionLocalOf<Cache> {
       error("coilHttpCache not provided")
   }
   ```

   Provide it in your activity/fragment:

   ```kotlin
   val cache = CoilUtils.createDefaultCache(this)
   val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this)
       .okHttpClient {
           OkHttpClient.Builder()
               .cache(cache)
               .build()
       }
       .build()

   setContent {
       CompositionLocalProvider(
           LocalImageLoader provides imageLoader,
           LocalCoilHttpCache provides cache,
       ) {
           // your application
       }
   }
   ```

   Get it in any composable

   ```kotlin
   val httpCache = LocalCoilHttpCache.current
   ```

   Then, regardless of where you store it in the DI or in the composition local, you can clear the necessary cache with the following code:

   ```kotlin
   val urlIterator = httpCache.urls()
   while (urlIterator.hasNext()) {
       if (urlIterator.next() == urlToRemove) {
           urlIterator.remove()
       }
   }
   ```
2. After downloading an image from the network, it is converted to `Bitmap`. These bitmaps are cached with [Memory cache](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/getting_started/#memory-cache), so you need to clear that as well. The easiest way, according to the documentation, is to specify a cache key, e.g. URL:

   ```kotlin
   rememberImagePainter(
       url,
       builder = {
           memoryCacheKey(MemoryCache.Key(url))
       }
   ),
   ```

   Then you can clean it up:

   ```kotlin
   val loader = LocalImageLoader.current
   // or out of composable
   val loader = Coil.imageLoader(context)
   // ..
   loader.memoryCache.remove(MemoryCache.Key(url))
   ```

The last step is to force image recomposition. You can do this with [`key`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#key(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Function0)), specifying the value to change, in your case `profileImgKey` should work:

```kotlin
key(profileImgKey) {
    Image(
        rememberImagePainter(
            // ...
```

Comment: Great answer - works. I had done everything already in my code, before seeing the crucial important last step here with key(..) to trigger recomposition.

Comment: I was using `Uri`, and it expects String from me. How do I know what exactly it should be?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to ensure that you get a fresh image, even when it changes  is to append a query parameter to the url with a random value. For example:

```
someurl/user1.jpg?49610269
```

And done like this:

```kotlin
val imageUrl = "someUrl/user1.jpg?" + (0..1_000_000).random()
```

If your url already has query parameters, just add a new parameter that your url doesn't use.

Images in caches are reused whenever the url (including the query string) does not change. By changing the url, you force Coil to obtain the most recent image.

Comment: This will just add new cache every time the image loads. This is not useful for the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to load a new image not cached in coil try the following code on that particular Image View :

```
imgVw.load(imgUrl) {
    memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
}
```

Comment: You didn't read question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is updating the url:

```
val builder: Uri.Builder = url.buildUpon()
builder.appendQueryParameter("imageCacheKey", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
val newUri = builder.build()
```

Comment: This will just add new cache every time the image loads. This is not useful for the above scenario.